# Como fazer o a baia "Home" e outras renderizarem a Pagina principal do meu documento html?

Tags: html, css

Cumprimentos! Criei uma baia de navegacao html-css com as seguintes caracteristicas:

```
<ul class "nav">
  <li><a href="# n a"> Home </a></li>
  <li><a href="# n b"> Contacto </a></li>
</ul>
```

mas o meu problema e que nao consigo fazer com que o usuario acesse a Pagina Principal clicando na baia Home. O que falta para que a baia "Home" renderize a pagina principal? Ajudem por favor. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Um bom começo seria remover os espaços dentro dos `href`, e acertar a sintaxe da classe (não interfere na navegação, mas falta um `=` entre o `class` e o `"nav"`. Isto supondo que sua navegação seja por JS, ou uma aplicação de página única. Se for de várias páginas, tem que por `href="nomedapagina.extensao"`, claro.

Comment: Obrigado. Mas ainda ainda estou duvidoso. Nao seria mais pratico com um exemplo?

Comment: Seria sim, pode [edit] a pergunta e colocar seu código atual (e mencionar o nome dos arquivose e como estão organizadas suas páginas) como exemplo, ajudaria a postarmos alguma resposta precisa.

Comment: Obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar. Ja descobri a resposta da minha pergunta e reconheco que estava mal formulada. Agradecido.

Comment: Ismael, você mudou completamente a pergunta na última edição, e por isso eu a reverti. Se tem uma nova dúvida, por favor poste uma nova pergunta separada mente, usando o botão que tem no topo do site. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, sua sintaxe está incorreta. Segue abaixo código certo.

```
<ul class="nav"> // faltou o '=' entre class e "nav";
  <li><a href="enderecodahome"> Home </a></li> //Haviam espaços no href.
  <li><a href="enderecodacontato"> Contacto </a></li> //Haviam espaços no href.
</ul>
```

Abaixo segue um exemplo de um menu horizontal no jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/hGF54/

Caso queira, você encontra muito conteúdo de HTML5 e CSS3 em diversos livros e video-aulas no youtube, recomendo este livro:
https://www.casadocodigo.com.br/products/livro-html-css

E estas video-aulas: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epDCjksKMok